# Error creating bean with name 'eurekaRibbonClientConfiguration'

Tags: netflix-eureka

I am using ZuulHandlerMapping and when I in lookupHandler return super.lookupHandler(urlPath, request) I usually got error with route:RibbonRoutingFilter. It is not a problem but I can't find out why it appears.

I am using spring boot 2.1.6.RELEASE and spring-cloud.version: Greenwich.SR2.

```
com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Filter threw Exception
at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:227) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.runFilters(FilterProcessor.java:157) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.route(FilterProcessor.java:118) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulRunner.route(ZuulRunner.java:96) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.route(ZuulServlet.java:116) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.service(ZuulServlet.java:81) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:165) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController.handleRequest(ZuulController.java:45) [spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:88) [spring-boot-actuator-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:114) [spring-boot-actuator-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:104) [spring-boot-actuator-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_191]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_191]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_191]
Caused by: org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.util.ZuulRuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'eurekaRibbonClientConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.run(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:127) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.runFilter(ZuulFilter.java:117) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:193) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
... 61 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'eurekaRibbonClientConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:139) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:414) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:845) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.context.named.NamedContextFactory.createContext(NamedContextFactory.java:136) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.context.named.NamedContextFactory.getContext(NamedContextFactory.java:101) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.SpringClientFactory.getContext(SpringClientFactory.java:131) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-ribbon-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.context.named.NamedContextFactory.getInstance(NamedContextFactory.java:145) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.SpringClientFactory.getInstance(SpringClientFactory.java:121) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-ribbon-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.SpringClientFactory.getClient(SpringClientFactory.java:55) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-ribbon-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.apache.HttpClientRibbonCommandFactory.create(HttpClientRibbonCommandFactory.java:57) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.apache.HttpClientRibbonCommandFactory.create(HttpClientRibbonCommandFactory.java:33) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.forward(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:165) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.run(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:119) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
... 63 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken
at com.netflix.client.config.CommonClientConfigKey.<init>(CommonClientConfigKey.java:255) ~[ribbon-core-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
at com.netflix.client.config.CommonClientConfigKey$1.<init>(CommonClientConfigKey.java:33) ~[ribbon-core-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
at com.netflix.client.config.CommonClientConfigKey.<clinit>(CommonClientConfigKey.java:33) ~[ribbon-core-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonUtils.initializeRibbonDefaults(RibbonUtils.java:67) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-ribbon-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.eureka.EurekaRibbonClientConfiguration.preprocess(EurekaRibbonClientConfiguration.java:148) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:363) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:307) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
... 84 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
... 96 common frames omitted
```

Can I ignore that error? Do not use a filter?

Comment: When you see this `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken` that means there is problem with lib version. Library you are using is ok but not version of it. So please check dependency for example `mvn tree` or equivalent of gradle.

Comment: Can I ignore this without changing of lib version?

Comment: Make mvn tree and see what version of `guava` you need in your server/application

Answer (score 0):

Adding below dependency solved my issue

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>19.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Version can be different.